# Should this answer about who played Seeker for the Gryffindor Quidditch game in the first Harry Potter book have been deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/163740/33591), to a question about who played Seeker for the Gryffindor Quidditch team in the first Harry Potter book, said this:

> During a conversation before the first quidditch match in 'Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets', while 'Wood' was going over tactics when they were changing for their first practice session, "...He had been unconscious in the hospital wing for the final match of the previous year meaning that Gryffindor had been a player short and had suffered their worst defeat in 300 years." This silences any speculation on the matter by answering definitively...

This actually answers the question pretty well. It gives a quote and states that this answers the question. It could do with a bit of editing, but it still answers the question - that they **didn't have a Seeker**. So, why was it deleted? Should we undelete it?

Comment: (I've now edited it a bit.)

Comment: To be fair, it does not necessarily mean they left the position of seeker empty; one of the others may have stepped up, leaving their position empty.

Comment: At first I thought it might have been because it was simply restating amflare's answer, but then i noticed the deleted answer was post first.... If it was not mod-deleted I would vote to undelete.

Comment: *Quidditch Through the Ages* specifies that should a team lose a player for whatever reason, that the player may not be replaced and the team must continue on with six players. It doesn't *explicitly* state that the players cannot switch positions, but I think that was rather heavily implied. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I saw this answer due to a "not an answer" flag raised by a high rep user with a high score for answers on [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter). The post did not seem to answer the question since it says that Gryffindor was a player short but gives no explanation whether or not the seeker position was left unfilled or if someone substituted as seeker. The post also had a uniformly negative response from the community at that time -- a negative score, a flag, and two negative comments -- so I deleted it.

Since the community has argued to undelete the post (and there's now an [upvoted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/164185/31936) which uses the same quote and provides more of an explanation) I have undeleted it.

Answer (score 14):

### Yes it should be undeleted

The answer clearly answers the question of *Who was the seeker*. It suggests **no-one** was the seeker.

> answering definitively that they were a player short.

This is (imho) exactly how the quote (provided above) reads. Although the answer may not *silence speculation* it clearly answers the question asked. It is my opinion (although I'm not here to sway voters) that this might in-fact be the best answer to this question.

Comment: You will have to get a moderator to agree (probably won't be hard), as the question was deleted by a mod. Regular users can not undelete it.

Comment: Yes, this, Good answer, Ed! :)